# How to suspend and resume a non-mainstream

Tags: java, multithreading

Don't look at all of my code, just the wait() and notify() methods I need to pause the run() method after the loop has finished its work and resume it in the onButtonClick() class, but when I do this I get an exception: current thread is not owner. How do I implement what I wrote in the title of the question

```
   private boolean isFirstPage;
    private CommandContext ctx;
    private ArrayList<String> linkQuestion;
    private Message message;

private int page;

public QuestionListThreads(boolean isFirstPage, CommandContext ctx, ArrayList<String> linkQuestion, Message message) {
    this.isFirstPage = isFirstPage;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.linkQuestion = linkQuestion;
    this.message = message;


}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
        if (isFirstPage) {
            for (; page < 3; page++) {
                eb.addField("page " + page, "[link]" + linkQuestion.get(page), false);
            }
            ctx.getChannel().sendMessage(eb.build()).setActionRow(Button.secondary("next", "next")).queue();
        } else {
            page = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, page++) {
                eb.addField("page " + page, "[link]" + linkQuestion.get(page), false);
                if (i == 2) {
                    message.editMessage(eb.build()).setActionRow(Button.secondary("next", "next")).queue();
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                        i = 0;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
   
public void onButtonClick(ButtonClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getComponentId().equals("next")) {
        new QuestionListThreads(false, null, QuestionListCommand2.getLinkQuestion(),
                event.getMessage()).notify();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that the exception has anything to do with `wait()` or `notify()`? What is the complete exception message and stack trace? Does it tell you from what line of your code the exception was thrown? Have you tried running the program in a debugger? Also, you say you want us to answer the question in your title, but it looks like you never finished typing it. Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the exception occurs in `event.getMessage()).notify()` it says so in the console, and I have already described everything I possibly understand about this problem in my question

Comment: "I have already described everything I possibly understand about this problem in my question" - Do not *describe* the error message, instead add to the question post **as is**. The error message could contain more information than noted in your description. Would you fully understand the error message... then you won't ask your question at all, don't you think so?

Comment: Solomon Slow has given a good answer. But I'd suggest refactoring your code. There is no need to create a new thread with each click of a button. Create one single thread (a Worker) which calls take() on a blocking queue in a while(true)-like loop. In onButtonClick() prepare an object with all required data and put it into the queue. This Job/Task Queue pattern will simplify the code and prevent some possible race conditions.

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing a tutorial on `wait()` and `notify()` such as  https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify. There are at least two problems here: 1) the code doesn't call `notify()` on the same object instance that `wait()` is called on; 2) the current thread doesn't own the monitor on the object that `notify()` is called on